# active state macro how to check if segment 2 is empty

Tags: templating, navigation, macro

I'm using a macro to check segment 1 to set an active state on my navigation and all is working correctly. However I would like to change it so that if segment_2 is not empty it doesn't display the active state, with the exception of being pagination in segment-2

so `domain.com/photography` and `domain.com/photography/p2` would get active but `domain.com/photography/slug` would not be active

my current code is:

macro:

```
{% macro is_active(segment) %}{% if craft.request.firstSegment == segment %}active{% endif %}{% endmacro %}
```

and nav:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="{{ macro.is_active('') }}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="{{ macro.is_active('photography') }}"><a href="/photography">All Photography</a></li>
  <li class="{{ macro.is_active('calendar') }}"><a href="/calendar">Archives</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I think you can test if it is a pagination page. So

```
{% if (craft.request.getSegment('2') == '') or (craft.request.getPageNum() != 1) %}active{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible macro. It uses [getSegment()](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getSegment) to get the second segment, and twig's [matches](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) operator to compare that segment to the page trigger. Note that there is a [pageTrigger](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#pageTrigger) setting, and this macro assumes you haven't changed that trigger.

```
{% macro is_active(segment) %}
  {% set firstSeg = craft.request.getSegment(1) %}
  {% set secondSeg = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
  {# is secondSeg a pagination segment? #}
  {% set isPagination = secondSeg and secondSeg matches '/^p[0-9]+/' %}

  {# active: firstSeg is our segment, and no secondSeg, or secondSeg is pagination seg #}
  {% if firstSeg == 'segment' and (not secondSeg or isPagination) %}
    active
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

You might also want to use the [twigperversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion) plugin which provides a `{% return %}` tag:

```
{% macro is_active(segment) %}
  ...
  {% return firstSeg == 'segment' and (not secondSeg or isPagination) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and then `{{ macro.is_active('photography') ? 'active' }}`

Comment: @AbbeyDesign is right: [getPageNum](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getPageNum) is a cleaner way to go